# Read from a file to get and print JSON data

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, iteration

Can someone help me understand how can I pass the results of a file/loop into another loop.

Basically I am trying to read financial instruments from Google finance. I am able to pass one symbol at time without any issues however, I am trying to learn to make this process dynamic and read the symbols from a file. So, in the future, I can change the file only.

So, this is what I am doing... reading the symbols from a file (symbols), looping through the file and passing the results to a json.dumps .

This works, however, I am getting only the last symbol and not all of them.

Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
reader = open('symbols','r')
refile = reader.readlines()
for sim in refile:
    quotes = json.dumps(getQuotes([sim]))
    data = json.loads(quotes)
for item in data:
    for k, v in item.items():
        #if "LastTradePrice" in k:
            print k, v
```

This is the file I am trying to read from:

```
GOOG
AAPL
IBM
CAR
GLD
```

Comment: What is `getQuotes`? That is important.

Comment: it is one of the objects provided by google finance ..... from googlefinance import getQuotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your indentation. You need the second for loop inside the first, so it can iterate over every value of `data`, rather than the last:

```
reader = open('symbols','r')
refile = reader.readlines()
for sim in refile:
    quotes = json.dumps(getQuotes([sim]))
    data = json.loads(quotes)

    for item in data:
        for k, v in item.items():
            #if "LastTradePrice" in k:
                print k, v
```

Comment: do you know how I can get name of ticker listed ? so, for the 1st one, it would be GOOG ... Last Trade Price 972.00

Comment: @JZi You mean `print sim, k, v`?